# How to create a loop within my function and then send it to my JSON file

Tags: javascript, ajax

So, I have my JSON file, but I need to send a certain URL to my JSON aswell with a loop.

this is where I set everything:

```
function setMainObjectArray() {
    var exercises = [];
    var eBlocks = $('.eBlock');

    eBlocks.each(function(i, eBlock) {
        var exObject = {
            word: $(eBlock).find('input.ExerciseGetWordInput').val(),
            syllables: []
        };

        $(eBlock).find('input.syllable').each(function(j, syll) {
            exObject.syllables.push($(syll).val());
        });
        exercises.push(exObject);
    });
    return exercises;
}
```

this is my ajax save function:

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
    console.log(setMainObjectArray());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveJson.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: getUrlParameter('id'),
            getExerciseTitle: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
            language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
            application: 'lettergrepen',
            'main_object': {
                title: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
                language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
                exercises: setMainObjectArray()
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        }
    }).done(function(response) {

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log(textStatus);
    });
}
```

and I think I need to loop something like this through my `function setMainObjectArray()`

```
var audioId = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf(exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'].toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
var audio_link = '';
if (audioId > -1) {
    exObject['audio'] = 'https://TheUrlServer' + MEDIAARRAY.audio.path + MEDIAARRAY.audio.files[audioId];
}
```

But I have no idea how to implement this into my function `setMainObjectArray`. I am not entirely sure if the loop is even written the correct way, i'm quite new to javascript and from there on to put it in my ajax call (since it's a link).

Comment: Can you please fix the title, currently it looks like you'd like to store a loop into JSON file.

Comment: "from there on to put it in my ajax call (since it's a link)."...actually it's just a string containing a URL. As to whether your loop is correct, you haven't explained what you're actually trying to achieve, so it's difficult to be sure. Have you tried it yourself?